Are multiple start rules for Fluent Bit Multiline Parsing possible?
Logs from multiple pods in my kubernetes cluster are ingested by Fluent Bit 3.1.7 for centralized logging. One of the pods contains a third-party, closed-source service where I cannot configure the multiline log output, so I'm thinking about the multiline-parsing configuration.
Is there a way to have multiple start_state entries leading to different continuation states? That would probably imply that a state has no unique rule. The Fluent Bit documentation clarifies that I can have multiple continuation states in my rules in my configuration, but it seems to talk about the start_state rather than a start_state.
(If I want just multiple start rules with the same continuation state, I could write a combined regex accepting both of them. Hard to read and possibly bad for performance.)

In fluent Bit, the multiline parser config does indeed allow you to define multiple continuation states for handling log messages but you cannot have multiple start_states entries leading to different continuation states.

When you have multiple multiline parsers, and want them to be applied one after the other, you should use filters.To apply the correct parser to your logs you can setup a filter in your Fluent Bit config to route logs based such as log source or other attributes.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your problem? If not let me know, I am happy to assist you further.

@ImranPremnawaz, the one start state part of the answer has kept me from that blind alley. Filtering is probably not my solution; either I accept that log lines during boot are disjointed and disordered (same millisecond on the timestamp) or I need a complex start condition. Still working on it.

Could you please let us know whether the issue has been fixed.If not,I am happy to assist further.
